# Is there a way to delete/clear a user property from Firebase Analytics?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I am using react-native-firebase and what I want to do is to remove user properties once the user do a log out. I think that some time ago just setting the user property to `null` worked, but it doesn't work anymore...

So here is the question, is there a way of remove an user property without setting them to a string saying "null" or something similar?

What I have tried to do is `analytics().setUserProperty("color", null)` and I saw in logcat

> No user property available for "color" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined"

Comment: Did you register your user property on the console first before using it in your code?

Comment: yes, I registered it